# DataTable plugin: order Columns correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using the DataTable plugin for my implementation. As I would like a column at the first position, whose values are at another position in the obtained json, I tried to use the [colReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) extension. The integration of that extension works fine (`"colReorder":true`), but when I try to change the position of my columns at initialisation time, the ordering process doesn't work. 

 Here is my code(I have put it in the fnInitComplete method of the plugin)

```
fnInitComplete:function( oSettings ) {
      var colReorder = new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder(table);
      var newOrder = [];
      newOrder.push(namePosition);
      for(var k=0;k<length;k++){
        if(k!=namePosition){
        newOrder.push(k);
        }
      }
      colReorder.fnOrder(newOrder);
```

I tried another options and positions of that code, but I can't make the reOrder work.If I log the `newOrder` variable it shows the correct order `[7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

The extension you linked allows the user to reorder columns with drag-and-drop. If you only want to set a different fixed order, you can do so with the [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option. It allows several ways to select which data is in each column. For example, if you set an integer, it renders the row data at that index:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Position", data: 1 }, // Use data at row[1]
            { title: "Name", data: 0 }, // Use data at row[0]
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k5afdb8s/

**Edited to add:**

In case you do want to use the extension, you can use the [colReorder.order](https://datatables.net/reference/option/colReorder.order) initialization parameter like in the example at the docs:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    colReorder: {
        order: newOrder
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! unfortunately in my case this is a bit more complicated as I have a dynamic column- and data generation and I don't want to use the order of the data I get from my json.